# 3D cubes draggable to grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d, html5-canvas

I'm working on a project for school in HTML5 en CSS3.
The goal of the project is to teach young children how to calculate simple equations.
The first step towards learning this is teaching them to recognize numbers in different shapes.

A first exercise would be:
showing a random number and letting the child select a 3D cube and dragging it inside of a grid.
The number of cubes in the grid should correspond ofcourse with the given number.
Example given below:

[image: Example of exercise]

I have no idea where to start. I know about a canvas in HTML5 but I'm not really familiar with it.

How can I snap the cubes into position when they come close?
How do I even draw a 3D cube in HTML5?
How can I check how many cubes were drawn on screen?
Can I draw something more pleasing for the children to look at than cubes, but still have a 3D effect?

Above all will it be capable of running on a iPad?
A dedicated App is out of the question as it should also be able to run on a desktop.

Hoping some of you might have a good solution.

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't use 3d , such a simple application, no need of it. The app will run on ipad if the ipad has the right browser. (I'm an android guy so meh.)

Comment: I wouldn't use 3D as well, but the client wants to have 3D. The picture just shows a simplified version. The final version will be a lot slicker.

Comment: If you want to go with 3D use http://threejs.org/ this library. (It will save your life.) If you want to test if it works on iPad or not, check this example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_cube

Comment: Is it true 3d though? If it's just the illusion of 3d then you can still use flat graphics in a way that looks 3d. If there's no need to rotate etc. the 3d objects or point of view then you can normally achieve 3d in a 2d way. To do the drag and drop look into mouse events in javascript ... basically mousedown sets a 'dragging' flag and then mouseup clears that and does a calculation to 'snap' to the grid etc. During the drag you run a function using setInterval that moves the graphic to the mouse position. That's a basic overview of it.

Comment: You should check out how http://www.khanacademy.org made it, because they made exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to make genuin 3D cube that will work on ios browser is [css3](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/cube.html)
You can put this cube(graphic representation) in to the present element that will represent its logically and use standard browser ways to manage `drag and drop`  [Usefully library](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and since this is DOM based implementation it can be styled with css. You can add color transition, animation delays or even deformation  with the [css3 transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) it will have much better performance than js animations. Also it's easier to implement. 
Here([video](http://vimeo.com/93206523), [images](http://the12principles.tumblr.com/)) is really cool animation guidance from Walt Disney Studios to help you make it visually appealing.